# Why can't I change the __class__ attribute of an instance of object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

o = object()
a = A()
b = B()
```

While I can change `a.__class__`, I can't do the same with `o.__class__` (it throws a `TypeError` error). Why?

For example:

```
isinstance(a, A) # True
isinstance(a, B) # False
a.__class__ = B
isinstance(a, A) # True
isinstance(a, B) # True

isinstance(o, object) # True
isinstance(o, A) # False
o.__class__ = A # This fails and throws a TypeError
# isinstance(o, object)
# isinstance(o, A)
```

I know this generally isn’t a good idea, since it can lead to some very strange behaviour if it is handled incorrectly. It's just for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: Built-in types sacrifice the dynamism of a user-defined type for reasons of efficiency. Note, another optional optimization is slots, which will similarly prevent this.

Answer (score 9):

**CPython** has a comment in [Objects/typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f4db4a0bab073b768fae958e93288bd5d24eadd/Objects/typeobject.c#L4003) on this topic:

> In versions of CPython prior to 3.5, the code in
>   `compatible_for_assignment` was not set up to correctly check for memory
>   layout / slot / etc. compatibility for non-HEAPTYPE classes, so we
>   just disallowed `__class__` assignment in any case that wasn't HEAPTYPE
>   -> HEAPTYPE.
>
> During the 3.5 development cycle, we fixed the code in
>   `compatible_for_assignment` to correctly check compatibility between
>   arbitrary types, and started allowing `__class__` assignment in all
>   cases where the old and new types did in fact have compatible slots
>   and memory layout (regardless of whether they were implemented as
>   HEAPTYPEs or not).
>
> Just before 3.5 was released, though, we discovered that this led to
>   problems with immutable types like int, where the interpreter assumes
>   they are immutable and interns some values. Formerly this wasn't a
>   problem, because they really were immutable -- in particular, all the
>   types where the interpreter applied this interning trick happened to
>   also be statically allocated, so the old HEAPTYPE rules were
>   "accidentally" stopping them from allowing `__class__` assignment. But
>   with the changes to `__class__` assignment, we started allowing code
>   like
>
> ```
> class MyInt(int):
> #   ...
> # Modifies the type of *all* instances of 1 in the whole program,
> # including future instances (!), because the 1 object is interned.
>  (1).__class__ = MyInt
> ```
>
> (see https://bugs.python.org/issue24912).
>
> In theory the proper fix would be to identify which classes rely on
>   this invariant and somehow disallow `__class__` assignment only for
>   them, perhaps via some mechanism like a new Py_TPFLAGS_IMMUTABLE flag
>   (a "blacklisting" approach). But in practice, since this problem
>   wasn't noticed late in the 3.5 RC cycle, we're taking the conservative
>   approach and reinstating the same HEAPTYPE->HEAPTYPE check that we
>   used to have, plus a "whitelist". For now, the whitelist consists only
>   of ModuleType subtypes, since those are the cases that motivated the
>   patch in the first place -- see https://bugs.python.org/issue22986 --
>   and since module objects are mutable we can be sure that they are
>   definitely not being interned. So now we allow HEAPTYPE->HEAPTYPE *or*
>   ModuleType subtype -> ModuleType subtype.
>
> So far as we know, all the code beyond the following 'if' statement
>   will correctly handle non-HEAPTYPE classes, and the HEAPTYPE check is
>   needed only to protect that subset of non-HEAPTYPE classes for which
>   the interpreter has baked in the assumption that all instances are
>   truly immutable.

#### Explanation:

**CPython** stores objects in two ways:

> Objects are structures allocated on the heap.  Special rules apply to
>   the use of objects to ensure they are properly garbage-collected.
>   Objects are never allocated statically or on the stack; they must be
>   accessed through special macros and functions only.  **(Type objects are
>   exceptions to the first rule; the standard types are represented by
>   statically initialized type objects, although work on type/class
>   unification for Python 2.2 made it possible to have heap-allocated
>   type objects too).**

Information from the comment in [Include/object.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f4db4a0bab073b768fae958e93288bd5d24eadd/Include/object.h#L14).

When you are trying to set a new value to `some_obj.__class__`, the `object_set_class` function is called. It is inherited from [PyBaseObject_Type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f4db4a0bab073b768fae958e93288bd5d24eadd/Objects/typeobject.c#L4793), see `/* tp_getset */` field. This function [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f4db4a0bab073b768fae958e93288bd5d24eadd/Objects/typeobject.c#L4053): can the new type replace the old type in `some_obj`?

Take your example:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

o = object()
a = A() 
b = B()
```

**First case:**

```
a.__class__ = B
```

The type of `a` object is `A`, the heap type, because it is allocated dynamically. As well as the `B`. The `a`'s type is changed without a problem.

**Second case:**

```
o.__class__ = B
```

The type of `o` is the built-in type `object` (`PyBaseObject_Type`). It is not heap type, so the `TypeError` is raised:

```
TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses.
```

Answer (score 7):

You can only change `__class__` to another type that has the same internal (C) **layout**.  The runtime generally knows that layout only if the type itself is dynamically allocated (a “heap type”), so with one exception explained in MiniMax’s answer that’s a necessary condition that excludes the built-in types as source or destination.  You also have to have the same set of `__slots__` with the same names.

Comment: Very informative, thanks. By the way, is `__class__` a *slot* attribute of `object` instances (so which can only be accessed through the descriptor `vars(object)['__class__']` or equivalently through the built-in function `type`)?

Comment: @Maggyero: The type itself is akin to a slot in that it is stored at a fixed offset in the object layout (which, for obvious reasons, must be the same across **all** types).  It’s quite a special case in the assignment code, of course.

Comment: So is it correct to say that `type(instance)` performs the same operation as `vars(object)['__class__'].__get__(instance)`, where `vars(object)['__class__']` is the data descriptor storing the value of the fixed offset used for locating the `__class__` slot on `object` instances?

Comment: Or `type(instance)` does a completely different thing?

Comment: @Maggyero: I believe those operations are indeed equivalent.